expo.modules.interfaces.filesystem.AppDirectories not found
I'm migrating my react native app to use expo and expo cli. All is good except I see following Warning/Error and icons are not loading.
Error: Call to function 'ExpoAsset.downloadAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: Module 'expo.modules.interfaces.filesystem.AppDirectories' not found. Are you sure all modules are linked correctly?

I have no idea what can be causing it

Do you use useFonts hook from expo-font?

I found an old config in my package json which was excluding filesystem from expo since I wasn't using expo except for 2 packages. removing it resolved this issue.

can you specify what did you change in your package.json?

I had following in my package.json
"expo": {
"autolinking": {
"exclude": [
"expo-file-system"
]
}
}
